# How to compile a GWT project using maven ONLY

Tags: java, maven, gwt, compilation

I have a GWT project that I currently compile using `Eclipse GWT plugin`, but now I would like to make my project compilable independently from the IDE, and the approach is to use Maven only.

From my research I found out that you need to add the `GWT Compiler plugin` to the `pom.xml` in order to compile the code from Java to Javascript files (*the JS files can be later packaged inside a war*), but I can't seem to find the compiler dependency in maven repository nor a good documentation of the compiler. Can you post a "basic" working pom.xml file that can be used to compile a Hello world GWT project, that would be very appreciated, Thank you.

**EDIT:**

- I'm using GWT 2.7.0

Comment: What version of GWT are you using?

Comment: @tgdavies I'm using GWT 2.7.0

Comment: Did you try to use a GWT archetype to generate the starting `pom.xml`?

Comment: Have you looked at https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/index.html ?

Comment: No I haven't checked these archetypes, I will be checking them out then give a feedback. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Yassir Archetypes should help for most of such cases, because they can generate the rest of the boilerplate required for a particular project stack. I remember coding in GWT 5-6 years ago, and for some reason I didn't use archetypes trying to figure out the whole build and run cycle for a modular GWT project. It resulted in much wasted time trying to figure out what's gone wrong. So either tgdavies' idea or https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/ (last in 2017) would most likely work you.

Comment: @fluffy It's true that using the archetypes needs some further configuration and restructuring of the existing project, as for the link you provided I think it is the compiler I've been looking for, and it seems to have a pretty decent documentation, I'll try to integrate it in my existing pom and see if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the gwt-maven-plugin. You have mentioned you have the Eclipse GWT plugin already, so you can create a new GWT project (e.g. right click on the Project Explorer -> New -> Other... -> GWT Web Application Project). Fill in the project name and package and make sure to enable the checkbox "Generate a Maven Project". Then you have a working sample of a pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.world.hello</groupId>
   <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>com.world.hello.HelloWorld</name>
   <properties>
      <!-- Setting maven.compiler.source to something different to 1.8
         needs that you configure the sourceLevel in gwt-maven-plugin since
         GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8 (see gwt-maven-plugin block below) -->
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <!-- Don't let your Mac use a crazy non-standard encoding -->
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
         <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
         <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
         <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.11</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process-classes" update them in DevMode -->
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
      <plugins>
         <!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc-8</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                     <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <moduleName>com.world.hello.HelloWorld</moduleName>
               <moduleShortName>HelloWorld</moduleShortName>
               <failOnError>true</failOnError>
               <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
               a different source language for java compilation -->
               <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
               <!-- Compiler configuration -->
               <compilerArgs>
                  <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
                  <arg>-compileReport</arg>
                  <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
               </compilerArgs>
               <!-- DevMode configuration -->
               <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
               <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
               <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
               <startupUrls>
                  <startupUrl>HelloWorld.html</startupUrl>
               </startupUrls>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <!-- Skip normal test execution, we use gwt:test instead -->
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
               <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Running `mvn clean install` on the console will compile your project using Maven. Or you right click your project on the Project Explorer and select Maven -> Update Project...

Sometimes, after creating the GWT Maven Project, Eclipse doesn't automatically recognize it as a Maven Project. If that is the case, right click your project on the Project Explorer and select Configure -> Convert to Maven Project.